# Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test reports "U" instead of "Z" in SPSS

Tags: spss, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Given two variables A and B with 35 random data points (generated with Excel in the range of 0 to 1), we applied
Analyse -> Nonparametric Tests -> Legacy Dialogs -> 2 connected Samples
in SPSS and marked "Wilcoxon" as test, which should perform the the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. All over the internet you find examples of the test reporting a "Z" value. However, our report is

Teststatistics$_a$

U: -1.032$_b$

Asymp. Sig. (2-sided): .302

a: Wilcoxon-Test
b: based on negative ranks

Why does the test not report a "Z" and how should we modify to obtain a "Z" rather than a "U"?

EDIT: Here's what we did and the output, and the original data is in my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5akfSYd7Sm2OHhVSGlMUWhVSm5jZ0NXMmNsalp6clQtSWYw/view?usp=sharing).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What SPSS version are you using? My version 22 displays Z. But in any case you can look into SPSS algorithms (in Help) to find out how U and Z are connected.

Comment: It is SPSS version 22. And sadly enough, I was not able to find any mention of U in the help concerning the Wilcoxon signed Rank Test.

Comment: I see. Sorry for saying about U. U pertains to Mann-Whitney test. Well, back to your problem. My version is patched 22.0.0.2 Win 64bit. Visit IBM SPSS site to download patches. The "U" might probably be a lapse in the output and being really meant is Z. Can you post a small data snippet and the result in your question so that I could compare your and my figures?

Comment: I added a link to the data, as well as screenshots of our procedure and a screenshot of the output to the original post. Thank you for the efforts you put into this!

Comment: Yes, your result is correct. But "U" is a typo. My SPSS displays it as "Z". One reason may be, as I supposed, that my version is patched while yours probably not. Another reason is that the typo is only in your language of output. Try to go to Edit-Options and set to English output: will the typo persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of ttnphns, we were able to detect the error. It is, as a matter of fact, the German SPSS settings. Switching to English, the test immediately showed a Z value.
Will now try to see whether patching the software in the German version helps.